# Reasons why server application stops responding

Tags: php, session, server

The question is a bit theoretical, but i need the answer to solve my practical problem.
**What are the reasons why server PHP application stops responding to device with some IP?**
Short description of sympthoms:
- iOS mobile application connects to some server PHP application via URL
- sometimes application just shows "no connection". I found that application stops responding to this IP in general - i cannot even go to this URL via browser
- logs are clean (both access and error logs do not get any record)

**Could You describe some ideas, what could cause this?**

Thank You!

Comment: Too many invalid logins? IP beeing blocked by a hosting provider? Internet connection problems? Restart apache and php? Some ideas..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Connection Problems... where to start?

First thing is first, what stops responding, the server application or the iOS application?

Now on to major details.

1. Test your DNS, routing and network troubleshooting.
2. Check your connection methods from the iOS app.
3. Access logs should ALWAYS have at least a failure, so you're probably running into a problem in networking.

### Networking

There's whole host of possible causes here, from your hosting provider's network routing, to the iOS devices service provider. If your [DNS record is correct](http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/), and you've gotten a good [traceroute](http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=trace&host=127.0.0.1) to your server IP, there's only a few dozen other locations the problem could be at:

1. Server hosts config.
2. Hosting firewall.
3. Apache Virtualhosts or .htaccess handling of request.
4. iOS device service provider blocking traffic. Good luck if this is the case.
5. Other IP routing issue at your datacenter or with the service-provider.

### What's the first thing you should do?

If the traceroute doesn't shine a nice bold beacon on the problem, then you'll have to go with packet-tracing, I'd start you with [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

If you can't reach your url from a browser, that's probably the first thing you should get working.

Comment: If you sometimes get a connection, and sometimes don't... you may be running into an issue with max-connections, or a timeout issue on your server. Both of those cases should have some logs accompanying them, so you're in need of some in-depth sysad efforts.

Comment: Alternatively, intermittent connectivity can also be caused by IP collisions or other routing issues. Both should be made clear by a few repeated traceroutes.